# Вывод всех строк с базы данных selector multiple

Tags: php, mysql

требуется помощь,есть таблица, в ней есть id сериала - `tid` и id жанра - `jid` хочу сделать поиск по жанрам но поиск ищет строки где есть последний из выбранных пользователем жанра, для поиска стоит select multiple, нужно сделать так чтобы из базы данных выводились строки где есть сразу все выбранные жанры пользователем а не последний, вот код селектора -

```
<select name="sjanrs[]" id="janrs" class="chosen-select" multiple data-placeholder="По каким жанрам искать">
                                <option                             value="1">
                    Альтернативная история
                </option>
                                <option                             value="2">
                    Альтернативная реальность
                </option>
                                <option                             value="3">
                    Ангелы
                </option>
                                <option                             value="4">
                    Андроиды
                </option>
                                <option                             value="5">
                    Антивойна
                </option>
                                <option                             value="6">
                    Антиутопия
                </option>
                                <option                             value="7">
                    Баскетбол
                </option>
                                <option                             value="8">
                    Безумие
                </option>
                                <option                             value="9">
                    Бисёнэн
                </option>
                                <option                             value="10">
</select>
```

Код обработчика PHP Но он видимо как-то не правильно работает -

```
    foreach ($_POST['sjanrs'] as $janr) {
    $jid = (int)$janr;
    $Result = mysqli_query($CONNECTDB, "SELECT `tid` FROM `janrs` WHERE `jid` = $jid");
    }
```

Comment: `WHERE jid IN (1,2,3,4)`

Comment: не подходит такой вариант

Comment: И чем же не подходит?

Comment: наверное потому-что у меня при выводе int(3) int(6) int(7) выбранные жанры сохраняются вот таким вот образом, проверил за счет var_dump

Comment: оно выводиться в порядке возрастания и из этого  массива по самому большему числу идет поиск

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$sjanrs = $_POST['sjanrs'];
array_walk($sjanrs, function (&$janr) {
    $janr = (int)$janr;
})    
unset($janr);

$result = mysqli_query($CONNECTDB, "SELECT `tid` FROM `janrs` WHERE `jid` IN (implode(',', $sjanrs))");

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    // $row['tid']
}
```

Comment: После var_dump выдает значение NULL

Comment: :) var_dump чего?

Comment: var_dump (mysqli_fetch_assoc($result));

Comment: ааа я лошара массив заэксплодил вместо имплода :Р

Comment: Почти помогли, большое спасибо на этом))Но теперь ищется те сериалы в которых есть хотя-бы лишь один из выбранных жанров, а мне нужно чтобы сразу все))